# How to disable HTML tags from tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tinymce

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g2nry5ifx0x9v52/2013-12-20%2011_20_26-Ingage%20Admin%20Panel.png

Hello i want to not saw the **strong>>em** from my tinyMce. Knows anyone how to do it?
Check out the photo to understand what i want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the bottom toolbar using this tinymce config parameter:

`statusbar : false,`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wordpress install this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/
This plugin will help to customize the tinyMCE Editor.

Otherwise you can set "valid_elements"

```
tinyMCE.init({
       valid_elements : "..................."
});
```

valid_elements: "@[class],p[style],h3,h4,h5,h6,a[href|target],strong/b,div[align],br,table,tbody,thead,tr,td,ul,ol,li,img[src]"

Refer : http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration:valid_elements