# Dynamics 365 Email rich text box element path cannot be removed by xrmtinymce

Tags: tinymce, dynamics-crm, richtextbox

[image]

Dynamics 365 version 9
Ultimate goal is to remove the circled element path in the rich text box in the email.

I used XRMTinyMCE but think that I disconnected using it. When I check the solution Web Resource, there's nothing there referencing XRMTinyMCE.

I also tried to change code by add "statusbar: false" by referrencing to [How to disable HTML tags from tinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700257/how-to-disable-html-tags-from-tinymce), but seems no matter how I change the app.js, even commenting out `<script src="app.js"></script>` in index.html, and then publish all, no changes are reflected in the rich text box in the email form.

What else could I try please?

Answer (score 0):

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/270091

Actually I posted in the community and the 2 replies helped answer and solve my question.

Thank you.

CK Editor built-in feature. 
Quote from the link: Dynamics 365 email form uses CKEditor that comes out of the box. You can modify the Config.js for CKEditor and add the following line to hide the html tags at the footer:

config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';

Hope that helps.

Comment: You may need to share the context here which helped you from the link/community answer.. Link only answer may lose its value when link expires/broken..